# Perform UPDATE before INSERT with one flush() in Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the Test Entity with `uniqueConstraints` on the `value` field.

I want to add some new Test entity and update some existing Test entity with one `flush()` like:

```
 $new = new Test;
 $new->setValue('existing value');

 $old = $em->getRepository('TestBundle:Test')->findOneByValue('existing value'); 
 $old->setValue('new value);

 $em->flush();
```

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'existing value'`

It happens because the old Entity is not updated before inserting the new Entity.

Is it possible to do it with ONE flush()?

Comment: May i ask how did you handle this issue? I'm having same issue and so far only solution i've came up with is to disable UQ constaint and ensure on validation level that entities are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont think so. Flush is executing UnitOfWork::commit method that at first executes inserts and after that updates:

```
try {
        if ($this->entityInsertions) {
            foreach ($commitOrder as $class) {
                $this->executeInserts($class);
            }
        }

        if ($this->entityUpdates) {
            foreach ($commitOrder as $class) {
                $this->executeUpdates($class);
            }
        }

        // Extra updates that were requested by persisters.
        if ($this->extraUpdates) {
            $this->executeExtraUpdates();
        }

        // Collection deletions (deletions of complete collections)
        foreach ($this->collectionDeletions as $collectionToDelete) {
            $this->getCollectionPersister($collectionToDelete->getMapping())->delete($collectionToDelete);
        }
        // Collection updates (deleteRows, updateRows, insertRows)
        foreach ($this->collectionUpdates as $collectionToUpdate) {
            $this->getCollectionPersister($collectionToUpdate->getMapping())->update($collectionToUpdate);
        }

        // Entity deletions come last and need to be in reverse commit order
        if ($this->entityDeletions) {
            for ($count = count($commitOrder), $i = $count - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
                $this->executeDeletions($commitOrder[$i]);
            }
        }

        $conn->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->em->close();
        $conn->rollback();

        throw $e;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't you add $em->persist($new); after $new->setValue('existing value');?

Comment: Please avoid asking questions in answers. In case this is meant to be an answer in the shape of a rhetoric question please add an explanation of how this is relevant. And rephrase to avoid the question.

Comment: This post doesn't look like an attempt to answer this question. Every post here is expected to be an explicit attempt to *answer* this question; if you have a critique or need a clarification of the question or another answer, you can [post a comment](/help/privileges/comment) (like this one) directly below it. Please remove this answer and create either a comment or a new question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)